# C# + XNA: Location of Sprite Folder and Sprites after Compile

Tags: c#, xna

I am trying to program an automatic Resource Loader for my project and so it is going well. But I am stuck on the loading of the sprites. I used this for checking the file exists

```
if (File.Exists(contentManager.RootDirectory + "/Sprites/" + spriteName + ".png"))
```

However it never finds the file, even though the file exists in the Content of the project. I have checked the folders and found that the .pngs are replaced by .xnb files. So I tried changing the file extension and then was given an error in the Sprite Load function

```
return contentManager.Load<Texture2D>(assetName);
```

It only happens if I change it from being a typical image file (png, bmp, etc). Can someone explain why this is the problem and how I can get around this? I have had no experience in the xna file extensions and can not find the answers I need. What I want is to load a new image into the project providing it exists in the Content Directory after compile

While on the topic, will the Sounds and Music be effected by the Compiler?

Comment: As Blau said, the XNA framework exports content as 'XNB' files, so you just need to replace `.png` to `.xnb`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use a content project, the resources are imported, processed and write to disk again as xnb files.

If you want to dynamically load resources you have to compile files on the fly through the content builder or avoid using the content project.

Microsoft provides examples like this to load content dynamically: http://xbox.create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/winforms_series_2

if you want to distribute the application, the runtime xna is not enoigh,  you need full xna framework and visual studio installed to work.

if you want the original files in the content project, you have to change their "copy to output folder" property  to "copy always", and realize that the compiled results will be at "project folder\bin\debug\content"

Comment: "if you want the original files in the content project, you have to change their "copy to output folder" property to "copy always", and realize that the compiled results will be at "project folder\bin\debug\content""

Interesting. Would you say this is the more ideal approach due to dynamic loading requiring full installation?

Comment: if you only need textures maybe... if you want to load 3d models you will have to import them by yourself, because the model class can't be used so easily.

Comment: Only one way to find out :)
As long as the image files can be made into Texture2D files after compilation, I see no reason why it would not work